# How to move files from Master to Main branch in Git

Tags: git, github, git-branch

This is the link to my Github Repository.

https://github.com/SparshBohra/Skin-Lesion-Detector

How do I move my 2 folders from the master branch to the main branch?

Also, how do I get the coding languages used, to show up as other repositories do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In git, it's very easy and straight forward to use branches.
Whenever you are done with your development (assuming on a side branch) you simply need to `merge` it back to the desired branch.

[image]

---

#### Pull Request

A better and much more recommended way is to open a pull request
[image]

---

Using a pull  you can do a code review as well with the ability to update/modify your branch and track all the changes
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can merge those branches. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge
2. AFAIK github is doing it automatically.